# Javabeans with jsp:useBean. How do they work? I don't understand

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, javabeans

I have to get 2 numbers and an operation from a jsp file, using a java bean. After submitting the numbers, take them to a servlet from that Java Bean and return an result of them. Problem is that the java bean fields are never completed with the numbers written in textboxes.
So, I have, index.jsp's body:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>
    <FORM METHOD="POST" action="Controller">
        N1: <input type ="text" name="nr1" value="0">
        op: <input type ="text" name="op" value="+">
        N2: <input type ="text" name="nr2" value="0">
        <INPUT class ="button" TYPE="submit" NAME="actiune" VALUE="Calculate"/>
    </FORM>
    <jsp:useBean id="binOp" class="beans.BinaryOperation" scope="session"/>
    <jsp:setProperty name="binOp" property="*"/>
</body>
```

The servlet's processRequest method, Controller.java, placed in package servlets:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    BinaryOperation binOp = (BinaryOperation) session.getAttribute("binOp");

    try {
        if (!binOp.isComplete()) {
            System.out.println(binOp.getNr1() + binOp.getNr2() + binOp.getOp());
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        } else {
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet Controller</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Bean in controller " + binOp.getNr1() + "__" + binOp.getOp() + "__" + binOp.getNr2() + "</h1>");
            out.println(binOp.toString());
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }



    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

And the bean, BinaryOperation, placed in package beans:

```
package beans;


public class BinaryOperation {

private String nr1;
private String op;
private String nr2;

public void setNr1(String nr1) {
    this.nr1 = nr1;
}

public void setOp(String op) {
    this.op = op;
}

public void setNr2(String nr2) {
    this.nr2 = nr2;
}

public String getNr1() {
    return nr1;
}

public String getOp() {
    return op;
}

public String getNr2() {
    return nr2;
}

public boolean isComplete() {
    return !(((nr1 == null) || (nr1.length() == 0))
            || ((op == null) || (op.length() == 0))
            || ((nr2 == null) || (nr2.length() == 0)));
}
}
```

In the Apache log I have next output from the if statement(see the servlet - System.out.println(binOp.getNr1() + binOp.getNr2() + binOp.getOp());): 
nullnullnull

Where is my mistake?

Comment: When you logged the values in the servlet, right before the `try` keyword, were the values set?  That is, can you verify the values you enter are making their way to the servlet?  I generally but these things in the Request object, by the way.

Comment: Can you explain to me how the value in `<input type ="text" name="nr1" value="0">` gets into the bean?

Comment: @Tony Ennis: As you can see, I try to take the bean from the request's session.

Comment: @Tony Ennis: II-nd question, I thought using this: <jsp:setProperty name="binOp" property="*"/>, will complete the beans, fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've did one more jsp file between index.jsp and Servlet:

```
 <jsp:useBean id="binOp" class="beans.BinaryOperation" scope="session"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="binOp" property="*"/>.
```

This did the "magic".

Comment: My answer resolved the problem. Your answer was very good, but did not solved the problem. I am sorry.

Comment: You shouldn't be angry because of this, and unrate my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The bean is only a Java class for hodling properites with getters and setters. It does not have any magic properties and does not fill itself. It just a type of object, like a pattern. This is how they work. You must manually fill the properties you want with the appopriate setSmth method.

Comment: How do I get the values from textboxes? And set them into the bean?

Comment: Can you tell us what his jsp's `<jsp:useBean ...` and `<jsp:setProperty...` do?

Comment: They do nothing in this case obviously :) I am just answering the title of the question. I don't have time to go over all the code. Sorry.